# Expected value of condtional expected value

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Consider Brownian motion $W=\{W(t)\}$ with its natural filtration $\{F(t)\}$, $t \in [0,T]$
Furthermore consider the process $X=\{X(t)\}$ is $F(t_{k-1})$ measurable with $0=t_0<t_1<.....<t_n=T$, where $X(t)=X_k$ for $t \in [t_{k-1},t_k]$ and $k=1,..,n$. Why can I state the following:

$$\mathbb{E}\left[X_k \left(W(t_k)-W(t_{k-1})\right)^2\right]= \mathbb{E}\left[X_k \mathbb{E}\left[(W(t_k)-W(t_{k-1}))^2| F(t_{k-1})\right]\right] $$

What theorem do I use to insert the extra cond. expectation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a theorem known as the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) that, for a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$, for any sub-sigma algebras $\mathcal{G_1} \subseteq \mathcal{G_2} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$, you have
$$ \mathbb {E} [\mathbb{E} [X\mid {\mathcal {G}}_{2}]\mid {\mathcal {G}}_{1}]=\mathbb{E} [X\mid {\mathcal {G}}_{1}]\quad {\text{(a.s.)}}$$
(the proof is in the linked article)

In your case, you just have to apply it for $\mathcal{G_1} =\sigma(\Omega) = \{\varnothing, \Omega \} $ and $\mathcal{G_2} = F(t_{k-1})$ to get your result.

Comment: Thank you very much. Does it not have to be the other way around. $G_1= \Omega$?

Comment: Oh yes you're right sorry, I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Is it trivial that $E[X | \sigma(\Omega)] = E[X]?$ I cannot see that right now.

Comment: Well, if you recall the definition of conditional expectation, $Y = \mathbb{E}[X|\sigma(\Omega)]$ has to be $\sigma(\Omega)$ measurable so it is necessarily a constant. $Y$ also has to be such that $\mathbb{E}[Y\mathbf{1}_A] = \mathbb{E}[X\mathbf{1}_A]$ for all events $A$ in $\sigma(\Omega)$. Taking that equality for $A = \Omega$, you see that you must have $Y = \mathbb{E}[X]$. I would not say it's "trivial", but intuitively it means that "the best approximation of $X$ I can make with no specific information is the average value of $X$", which kinda makes sense.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks again :)